# How can I avoid StackOverflow Error on Julia?

Tags: out-of-memory, julia, stack-overflow

This is a little product function that transform a list of constants, a list of operators and another list of constants to a Julia `Expr`.
The function is working for smalls sets of constants, however for more a list of 100 constants and 5 operators, the function throws a StackOverflow.

```
function applyProduct(left, operators, right)
    prod = Iterators.product(left, operators, right)
    prod = Iterators.vcat(prod...)
    return Iterators.map(x -> Expr(:call, Symbol(x[2]), Symbol(x[1]), Symbol(x[3])), prod)
end
```

My function blows up at the vcat function:

```
ERROR: LoadError: StackOverflowError:
Stacktrace:
[1] promote_eltypeof(::Tuple{String,typeof(+),Expr}, ::Tuple{String,typeof(+),Expr}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at .\abstractarray.jl:1211 (repeats 8406 times)
[2] _cat(::Val{1}, ::Tuple{String,typeof(*),Expr}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at .\abstractarray.jl:1382
[3] #cat#104(::Val{1}, ::Function, ::Tuple{String,typeof(*),Expr}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at .\abstractarray.jl:1511
[4] (::getfield(Base, Symbol("#kw##cat")))(::NamedTuple{(:dims,),Tuple{Val{1}}}, ::typeof(cat), ::Tuple{String,typeof(*),Expr}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at .\none:0
[5] vcat(::Tuple{String,typeof(*),Expr}, ::Tuple{String,typeof(*),Expr}, ::Tuple{String,typeof(*),Expr}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at .\abstractarray.jl:1449
```

It's a stackoverflow error so the data is somehow stored on the stack. Should I declare something to keep it in-memory ?

I would like to apply this operation to a large sets of constants. Maybe I'm not using the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely want to pre-allocate. And avoid explicitly enumerating the `product` iterator and using maps

```
function applyproduct(left, op, right)
    itr = Iterators.product(op, left, right)
    thestack = Vector{Expr}(undef, length(itr))

    for (i, t) in enumerate(itr)
        thestack[i] = Expr(:call, Symbol.(t)...)
    end

    return thestack
end

N = 500
left = [String(rand('a':'z', rand(1:5))) for _ in 1:N]
right = [String(rand('a':'z', rand(1:5))) for _ in 1:N]
op = ["+", "-", "/", "^", "<", "≤"]

applyproduct(left, op, right)
# 1500000-element Array{Expr,1}:
#  :(wtolz + kzyxh)
#  :(wtolz - kzyxh)
#  ⋮
```

Also, you can avoid the `Expr` call with:

```
:($(Symbol(t[1]))($(Symbol(t[2])), $(Symbol(t[3]))))  
# :(adsf - sd)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not materialize the list until its elements are needed:

```
using IterTools
function applyProduct2(left, operators, right)
    prod = Iterators.product(left, operators, right)
    return IterTools.imap(x -> Expr(:call, Symbol(x[2]), Symbol(x[1]), Symbol(x[3])), prod)
end
```

note that you might to need install the `IterTools.jl` library.

Having that said your code crashes on `vcat` where you try to call it with a huge number of arguments. If you have to materialize use `vec(collect(prod))` instead.